# get checkbox value using angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a data in the form roles variable:

```
 $scope.roles = [
    {id: 1, text: 'a'},
    {id: 2, text: 'b'},
    {id: 3, text: 'c'},
    {id: 4, text: 'd'},
    {id: 5, text: 'e'},
    {id: 6, text: 'f'}
 ];
```

I am fetching all the roles into my html like below:

```
 <label ng-repeat="role in roles">
     <input type="checkbox" name="sportId" ng-required="!sportId" data-checklist-model="player.sport_id" data-checklist-value="role.id" ng-click="myFunction(role.id)"> {{role.text}}
 </label>
```

On every checkbox I want to call this `myFunction`:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(id){
    $http.get('v1/sp/' + $scope.player.sport_id + '/pstn')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.pstn = data.data;
    });
};
```

But it is calling once either I select `id` number 3 bring response that belongs to `id` number 3 and for text: c respectively if I select 1 then bring the response corresponding to the 1.

How could I get whole response i.e if I select 1 bring one value and I do select 2 it bring the value for 2 simultaneously and if I select 1,2,3 shows all three response not last select ids value that I select because right now it is happening:

```html
<div class="styled-select tab-content">
  <select name="position" ng-options="position.position_id as position.name for position in positions" ng-model="player.position_id" required>
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

It should go here:

```html
<section ng-init="tab = 1">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li ng-class="{ active:tab ===1 }">
      <a href ng-click="tab = 1">a</a> 
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active:tab ===2 }">
      <a href ng-click="tab = 2">b</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="panel" ng-show="tab === 1">
    <span playerposition></span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" ng-show="tab === 2">
    <span playerposition></span>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: It looks as though you override the `ptsn` variable each call you make. Do you want it to be aggregated?

Comment: yes what i want it should shows for every ids

Comment: I'm not sure how your logic works, but you can aggregate your `ptsn` like this: `$scope.pstn += data.data` (simple example of course)

Comment: for now what is happning if i select first id it shows me correct for first id data if i select 2nd id then it shows me first id data if i uncheck it shows me 2 id data i want which i select it shows up all data

Comment: No AranS  if i append it will bring all the data into one form i want to make it seperate

Comment: can you send additional code? like your form, the whole template, etc.

Comment: <div class="styled-select tab-content">
                  <select
                    name="position"
                    ng-options="position.position_id as position.name for position in positions"
                    ng-model="player.position_id"
                    required>
                    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

putting data in it

Comment: from what I see from checklist-model doc, $scope.player.sport_id should be an array. I am not sure if your appended URL works!

Comment: I strongly advise you put both the controller and your template code in the body question, there's not enough data

Comment: Updated @AranS please take a look

Comment: @Muthukannan you are correct i did but nothing happnd but player.sport_id is in array form